# How to add two numbers in the blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, count, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I need to add two numbers/amount displayed in my blade view, as shown in the image below
[image]

I need to display as 666.68 / 1000 AUD

Here's my `blade` codes

```
    <td>
          @foreach ($team->competitionPayments as $payment)
                {{ $payment->amount }}
          @endforeach

          <br>

         {{ $team->competitionPayments }}
         /
         @foreach ($team->competitions as $total)
          {{ $total->pivot->total_fee .' AUD'}}
         @endforeach
   </td>
```

Here's my `controller` function

```
public function detailedRegistrations($competition)
{

    $competitions = $this->competitionsRepo->findOrFail($competition);

    $teams = $competitions->teams()->get();

    $payments = $competitions->payments()->get();

    return view('competitions.detailed-registrations',
                    [
                        'teams'=>$teams,
                        'payments'=>$payments,
                        'competitions'=>$competitions,
                    ]
                );
}
```

Here's the `competitionPayments` relationship in the `Team model`

```
public function competitionPayments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompetitionPayment::class, 'team_id');
}
```

Please give me an idea of how to make this work

Comment: `$team->competitions->sum('total_fee')` ?

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul  no i need to get the total of the amount

Comment: then try `$team->competitionPayments->sum('amount')`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Success! it worked Thanks man !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here `competitionPayments` is a collection so you can apply `sum()` function on it like

```php
<td>
  {{ $payment->competitionPayments->sum('amount') }}
<br>
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<td>
    {{ $team->competitionPayments->sum('amount') }}
    /
    @foreach ($team->competitions as $total)
    {{ $total->pivot->total_fee .' AUD'}}
    @endforeach
</td>
```